# Check aws cloudfront function status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

I'm updating the AWS cloudfront function using commands

```
aws cloudfront  update-function
aws cloudfront  publish-function
```

and then in web console I see that status of my function become "Updating", saying that *The function is published to the live stage and its associated distributions are deploying the most recent changes.*

Is there a way to check when the function gets the Deployed status after Updating using the aws cli? When I run

```
aws cloudfront  list-functions
```

I get my function listed twice with both LIVE and DEVELOPMENT stages, that's it, no Updating

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aws cloudfront wait distribution-deployed` to check status of distribution.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/wait/distribution-deployed.html

Comment: Nope, status of distribution stays the same while its function is being updated, so that command is not helpful.